# Getting "access denied" starting service from code

Tags: c#, service, access-denied

I use this code to start a Windows service

```
public static bool StartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds, params string[] args)
{
    ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
    try
    {
        service.Start(args);
        TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
        service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But everytime I try this code I get an access denied.
I understand that this could be caused from UAC (the exe running this code is not running with elevated privileges).
What it's not clear to me is that if I start the same service using services panel, it runs: why? Services panel should be opened with the same user privileges, or not?
How can I start this service using my code without elevated privileges?

Note that the service is not written in C# and I don't have source code for it.
I tested this on Windows Seven (both 32 and 64 bit).

Comment: Starting a service using the Services MMC does not mean that the service will run with the logged on users credentials. If you right click on the service and select "Properties" then go to "Log On", you'll see the user account that the service is set up to run under.

Comment: Sir, ideally what i've found is that it is not possible to bypass UAC for unsigned applications. You will have to run your code IDE as administrator and then try running your application. So what i think is you cannot without elevated privileges.

Comment: @rsbarro: I know, service is run as LocalSystem account; but if I start it from services panel everything goes well, while performing same operation from code gives me "access denied"... I don't understand...

Comment: @Marco If you run the exe using elevated privileges, does it work?